# Distributed caching solution for WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, caching, distributed-caching

We have typical ASP.NET application with a web app & a phone client app which talks to a WCF Service which uses a SQL Server database. Currently we have only once instance of WCF service hosted in IIS but may decide to deploy to a webfarm in future.

We would like to cache relational data in a cache in WCF service side, that way both web app and phone app can benefit from it. **WCF service is purely stateless and we need to keep it that way.**

With those constraints, what are available technologies/solutions/thirdparty components that we can use to implement the caching on WCF service. Which ones work best in a webfarm scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Windows Server AppFabric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppFabric#Windows_Server_AppFabric)?  It will scale across your web farm and should be compatible with most server-based .NET solutions.

We use it quite extensively across our projects and it works quite well.

Comment: Is app fabric a stand alone component that I can install/deploy on my server? I was think it is more of a Azure cloud solution and the apps must be running inside Azure to benefit from it.

Comment: Yes, it can be deployed on your server.  There are two versions I believe, Windows Azure AppFabric and Windows Server AppFabric.  The former is the cloud-based option and the latter is the locally installed server-version.  Have a look at the wiki on AppFabric in general for the difference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppFabric

Comment: Yep. Thanks for pointing out this one. Are there any other alternate solutions?

Comment: I know this answer is three years old at this point, but anyone reading this should be aware of later developments. Microsoft recently announced that Windows Server AppFabric is being discontinued in 2017 and will no longer be supported. So this isn't a viable option anymore.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few third party options here:
NCache 
Memcached 
Redis 
AppFabric

This is just a few but there are others out there.

Answer (score 0):

[NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/index.html) can be a better option here. all you have to do is to create a caching tier in between WCF and SQL Server and then populate data in cache.  All the subsequent request of this data will be severed by cache.

Read the below mentioned article which will further clarify the concept of WCF caching.

[Scalable WCF Applications Using Distributed Caching](http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/articles/scalable-wcf-app-using-distributed-caching.html)