# Multi application cache - WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, caching

I am designing a shared "service/app" for caching .NET objects and access them from several applications (asp.net, winforms...). Is the WCF approach a good choice? I'd like also to allow events subscriptions for the applications to know when a cached object has been changed, or something like that.

What do you think?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778533/distributed-caching-solution-for-wcf-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is named Distributed Cache.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942840.aspx

In scenarios like yours the most efficient solution will be using some existing system instead of inventing own bicycle.

MS recently developed its own software that implements Distributed Cache. Software name is AppFabric. Actual version is 1.1. It can be used free of charge.

AppFabric consists of several features. You need to loock at `AppFabric 1.1 Caching Features`

Check this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334305 - Caching Features architectural overview

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19603 - samples

Comment: I'm not sure Appfabric is the best choice for my scenario. I don't need (at this moment) a distributed Cache, I need one "cache" where share some objects by different applications at the same time. Could I achieve that with Appfabric? I didn't find any information for this scenario.

Comment: @DMDeveloper Sorry for delay. "I need one "cache" where share some objects by different applications at the same time." - AppFabric allows you to do that.